# Visual studio code cmake causes error ld.exe: unrecognized option '--major-image-version'

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, raspberry-pi-pico

Using windows 10, I am trying to build example code for a W5100S-EVB-Pico.

I started in https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/getting-started-with-pico.pdf section 9.2 which sets you up to build on windows. I was able to build the examples files there using visual studio code.

Now I want to use the Wiznet. Starting in https://github.com/Wiznet/RP2040-HAT-C I follow directions in the file `getting_started.md` I then go to vs code, and follow the pattern from 9.2. I open the folder ...\RP2040-HAT-C\examples\http\server select the appropriate compiler, and click build. I get an error which leads me to add the line
`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)`
to CMakeLists.txt Build now results in the following:

```
[variant] Loaded new set of variants
[kit] Successfully loaded 5 kits from C:\Users\rw\AppData\Local\CMakeTools\cmake-tools-kits.json
[proc] Executing command: "D:\Program Files (x86)\Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi\12.2 rel1\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" -v
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" -Sd:/cygwin/home/rw/holden/RP2040-HAT-C/examples/http/server -Bd:/cygwin/home/rw/holden/RP2040-HAT-C/examples/http/server/build -G "NMake Makefiles"
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" -Sd:/cygwin/home/rw/holden/RP2040-HAT-C/examples/http/server -Bd:/cygwin/home/rw/holden/RP2040-HAT-C/examples/http/server/build -G "NMake Makefiles" exited with code: 1 and signal: null
[main] Configuring folder: server 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=D:\Program Files (x86)\Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi\12.2 rel1\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=D:\Program Files (x86)\Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi\12.2 rel1\bin\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe" -Sd:/cygwin/home/rw/holden/RP2040-HAT-C/examples/http/server -Bd:/cygwin/home/rw/holden/RP2040-HAT-C/examples/http/server/build -G "NMake Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
[cmake]   No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
[cmake]   contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
[cmake]   code such as
[cmake] 
[cmake]     project(ProjectName)
[cmake] 
[cmake]   near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().
[cmake] 
[cmake]   CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
[cmake]   line.
[cmake] This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.1
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.1
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/12.2 rel1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/12.2 rel1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe - broken
[cmake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:70 (message):
[cmake]   The C compiler
[cmake] 
[cmake]     "D:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/12.2 rel1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe"
[cmake] 
[cmake]   is not able to compile a simple test program.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   It fails with the following output:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     Change Dir: D:/cygwin/home/rw/holden/RP2040-HAT-C/examples/http/server/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-2zbfaa
[cmake]     
[cmake]     Run Build Command(s):nmake -f Makefile /nologo cmTC_d4dce\fast &&   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_d4dce.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_d4dce.dir\build
[cmake]     Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d4dce.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
[cmake]         "D:\Program Files (x86)\ARMGNU~1\12DBAB~1.2RE\bin\AR19DD~1.EXE"    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_d4dce.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c D:\cygwin\home\rw\holden\RP2040-HAT-C\examples\http\server\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-2zbfaa\testCCompiler.c
[cmake]     Linking C executable cmTC_d4dce.exe
[cmake]         "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E rm -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_d4dce.dir/objects.a
[cmake]         "D:\Program Files (x86)\ARMGNU~1\12DBAB~1.2RE\bin\ARM-NO~2.EXE" qc CMakeFiles\cmTC_d4dce.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\cmTC_d4dce.dir\objects1
[cmake]         "D:\Program Files (x86)\ARMGNU~1\12DBAB~1.2RE\bin\AR19DD~1.EXE" -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\cmTC_d4dce.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o cmTC_d4dce.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_d4dce.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\cmTC_d4dce.dir\linkLibs.rsp
[cmake]     d:/program files (x86)/armgnu~1/12dbab~1.2re/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: unrecognized option '--major-image-version'
[cmake]     d:/program files (x86)/armgnu~1/12dbab~1.2re/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: use the --help option for usage information
[cmake]     collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[cmake]     NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Program Files (x86)\ARMGNU~1\12DBAB~1.2RE\bin\AR19DD~1.EXE"' : return code '0x1'
[cmake]     Stop.
[cmake]     NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
[cmake]     Stop.
[cmake]     
[cmake]     
[cmake] 
[cmake]   
[cmake] 
[cmake]   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] See also "D:/cygwin/home/rw/holden/RP2040-HAT-C/examples/http/server/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[cmake] See also "D:/cygwin/home/rw/holden/RP2040-HAT-C/examples/http/server/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=D:\Program Files (x86)\Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi\12.2 rel1\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=D:\Program Files (x86)\Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi\12.2 rel1\bin\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe" -Sd:/cygwin/home/rw/holden/RP2040-HAT-C/examples/http/server -Bd:/cygwin/home/rw/holden/RP2040-HAT-C/examples/http/server/build -G "NMake Makefiles" exited with code: 1 and signal: null
```

Some googling also led me to add the line
`set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)`
to CMakeLists.txt, which now looks like

```
set(TARGET_NAME w5x00_http_server)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)

add_executable(${TARGET_NAME}
        ${TARGET_NAME}.c
        )

target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE
        pico_stdlib
        hardware_spi
        hardware_dma
        ETHERNET_FILES
        IOLIBRARY_FILES
        HTTPSERVER_FILES
        )

pico_enable_stdio_usb(${TARGET_NAME} 1)
pico_enable_stdio_uart(${TARGET_NAME} 0)

pico_add_extra_outputs(${TARGET_NAME})
```

I tried to fix the broken compiler error, which made things worse, and returning CMakeLists.txt to its former state did not get back to what is shown above. Is there some kind of 'clean' function I can do?

Comment: "I open the folder ...\RP2040-HAT-C\examples\http\server select the appropriate compiler, and click build." - `CMakeLists.txt` in the examples directory and below are NOT standalone, so they cannot be configured separately. You still need to configure the **whole project** (from that directory: https://github.com/Wiznet/RP2040-HAT-C). (Absence of  the `cmake_minimum_required` in the first line of `CMakeLists.txt` is the clear sign that given file cannot be configured standalone.)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2: Tsyvarev made a very good point in the discussion under this answer. Because your `CMakeLists.txt` is missing a `project(...)` line it most likely gets implicitly called by CMake on the first line. Specific variables such as `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` or for example `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` require to be set before the `project()` line. It is worth trying to update the `CMakeLists.txt` accordingly. However the first EDIT still holds place (which was also Tsyvarevs finding). You are most likely trying to build from an insufficient `CMakeLists.txt`

EDIT: I didn't notice what Tsyvarev mentioned in the comments, after looking at the appropriate `CMakeLists.txt` **I have to agree with him**. You are definitely also missing some targets and you've probably didn't give us the whole (new) error message. The missing targets here are (for example):

```
ETHERNET_FILES
IOLIBRARY_FILES
HTTPSERVER_FILES
```

You will most likely encounter errors regarding this as well. However the original error is truly tied to the `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)`.

---

Original post:

A missing `cmake_minimum_required()` should just throw a warning not an error IIRC.

The only `clean` function that exists in `CMake` is `rm [path-to-build-directory]`. When you issue the `cmake -S. -Bbuild` command (or similar) you create a build folder where `CMake` generates the file needed to compile the project.

As to your issue. The `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)` should be added to the **toolchain file** or at the very least be the first variable set in your `CMakeLists.txt`. I believe (and this is a wild guess) that it should be before the `cmake_minimum_required()` this is the same for variables like `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` etc.

What I would recommend is:

0. Move the `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)` to the top of the `CMakeLists.txt` file
1. Remove the `build` folder.
2. Run cmake and build it again.

If the above won't help then I need you to clarify for me this:

- By "I went back to VSCode" you mean you opened it up via the Developer prompt like the book you linked suggested.
- What commands do you pass to run cmake/build it, i.e. what happens if you run from the **Developer powershell/command prompt**: `cmake -S. -BbuildForStackOverflow -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Generic` and then build it from these generated files?

Comment: "you've probably didn't give us the whole (new) error message" - The error message is about failing to detect working compiler. That detection is performed when CMake processes `project()` call, and this call goes before using of `ETHERNET_FILES` and other targets, and before using `pico_enable_stdio_usb` and other pico-related functions. That is, the error message in the question post is the actual one.

Comment: I am not sure about this statement: " That detection is performed when CMake processes project() call ..." because you can write a CMake project without specifying `project(...)` and you can still define a different `CXX` compiler than the one specified in the toolchain files. I am however not sure about this.

As to the error that he posted it is related to the expected system settings the linker expects. And I am 100% certain that the `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)` should fix this.

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that `project()` call is actually missed in that `CMakeLists.txt`. But in that case CMake emits an implicit call: `CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first line`. "And I am 100% certain that the `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)` should fix this." - If implicit `project()` call is actually at the first line, then it is not affected by that setting of `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`, which occurs *later* in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev this is a very good point, I haven't thought about it that way. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was opening the 'server' folder and assuming that everything was there. I never could figure out where the 'toolchain file' was. The solution is to open the folder RP2040-HAT-C in VS code first and select the appropriate compiler. VS code then does the initial cmake with the .txt file in that directory. Now, on the status line in VS code, I can click 'all' next to build, select my desired target (server) and build. Success!

Thanks to everyone who helped me with this.